# Caracteres indesejados usando jquery + php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Estou com um pequeno problema, quando uso o append do jquery para exibir elementos retornados de uma consulta php.

Obs: esse não é o append completo, ele é um pouco extenso e coloquei só a parte que preciso que vocês vejam.

```
$("#topics").append('<div class="topic_sumario">'+dados.sumario+'</div>')
```

O sumário é um campo na minha tabela de tópicos que é adicionado e editado com uma textarea usando tinymce, o problema é que quando o append exibi o sumário ele está aparecendo todas as tags html vindas do tinymce, exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É como se não estivesse reconhecendo as tags e exibindo tudo como uma string

Quero que reconheça todas as formatações que o tinymce fizer, como por exemplo bold, italic, ou o embed de um video etc... mas do jeito que estar não vai dar certo

Comment: `console.log(dados.sumario);` mostra o que ? Qual a informação que foi de facto guardada na tabela do banco de dados  ?

Comment: No bd está armazenado tudo em utf8: "&#60;p&#62;teste de &#60;strong&#62;tags&#60;/strong&#62;&#60;/p&#62;" e o console.log exibi exatamente o que está no bd @Isac

Comment: `&#60;` é a mesma coisa que `&lt;` logo é apenas a representação do caratere `<` e não o próprio caratere. Se quiser pode literalmente substituir o que vem do banco com `replace` mas tenha cuidado que isso pode ser perigoso no que toca ataques *XSS*, isto é, assumindo que é o usuário que insere dados nessa tabela

Comment: Mas quais são minhas opções então além dessa? @Isac

Comment: O motivo pelo qual os carateres são guardados como `&lt;` e `&gt;` em vez de `<` e `>` é evitar esse tipo de ataques. Se tiver a certeza que só tem etiquetas não perigosas nos dados (`<script>` seria uma das perigosas) então é seguro fazer `$("#topics").append('<div class="topic_sumario">'+dados.sumario.replace(/&#60;/g, '<').replace(/&#62;/g, '>') +'</div>')`

Comment: A resposta abaixo não resolveu?

Comment: @ÐvÐ deu sim, é que esqueci de por como resolvido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize essa função nativa do *PHP*: [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Ex.:

```
<?php
    echo html_entity_decode('&#60;p&#62;teste de &#60;strong&#62;tags&#60;/strong&#62;&#60;/p&#62;');

    // Saída: teste de tags
```

Recomendo que leia a documentação da função, pois existem outros parâmetros extremamente importantes a serem passados, já que definem o *charset* da conversão e como será o tratamento das aspas e apóstrofos.